# Is there a way to detect when users are on a certain part of a third party app?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been approached by a client to try and figure out if we can send notifications when the user of our app is on the checkout page of another app.
In this specific instance, they want us to send a notification when the user is on Amazon's checkout page.

Is this even feasible? I'm stumped to be honest. The best I can think of is to send a notification when a third party is opened, but not when they are on a specific part of the the third party app.

Answer (score 2):

No, all apps are sandboxed and can't access such information about other apps.

I'd be fairly sure that, even if possible, such push notifications wouldn't be viewed kindly by apple. Trying to hijack another apps flow, is probably a big no no